# Icon that represents 'Delivered Fully Assembled'

Tags: icon

Can anyone think of an icon that represents delivered fully assembled? Only requirement is no tools.

Client has said no to tools or screws etc, as he thinks it leads people to think you might need them. Current icon below.

[image: Delivered Fully Assembled]

Comment: You could always just try a "no tools" icon (image of a wrench in the universal circle & slash icon).  Would there be any accompanying text or tooltip to help explain the icon?

Comment: Thanks Amelia, its just that the client has said no to tools or scews etc. It sits above the words Delivered Fully Assembled, but I think I might change it to Ready to Use - any thoughts on that? I also added the current icon above.

Comment: Your client is wrong. That icon makes perfect sense.

Comment: What type of product is it?  And more to the point, is it *one* type of product or a wide variety?

Comment: My thoughts exactly DA01. Office Furniture, 95% swivel chairs.

Comment: What about a little re-think: instead of thinking "fully assembled", think "ready out of the box", "key ready" (as when your house is finished, and you just get the keys to move in).

Comment: If it's sitting above the "Delivered fully assembled" text... then just an image of a chair.

Comment: I agree with the client... People could look at that icon and not notice the strikethrough because it's quite subtle and looks separate, and if they did, they could think it means "Screws not included, buy your own screws before beginning self-assembly"... It's always amazing how wrongly people can interpret things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough idea, and "flatish", in the same line that has been discussed.[image]

Comment: It makes sense and I can't think of any other possible meaning for it to convey, so the only question would be is it easily understandable? Hard to judge while it's in this context (explained here).

Comment: I guess it depends on the type of product. If I see this icon besides an IKEA product on their website, I would assume it is not flat-packaged, because I know the rest of them are and I have the expectation of receiving a flat box from IKEA. But you are right, in a different context it might not be clear. I guess the client would have to be the judge (or a focus group, if anyone still has the time for those).

Comment: Well done. I think this is the one Ill go for. I will post the final When Im back at work monday morning. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I liked Random's idea of ready out of the box. Pretty literal, but: How about a chair coming out of the box?

[image]

<sub>Source: [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/60885/chair_furniture_icon#size=128)</sub>

[image]

<sub>Source: [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/196741/box_open_package_products_icon#size=128)</sub>

Now imagine something like this but that actually looks decent:

[image]

Another idea I just had, what about a chair that looks like it's *been assembled*? Something like the last image in this series:

[image]

<sub>[Source](http://www.designbuzz.com/protective-coloring-chair-is-transformed-from-a-box/)</sub>

Not sure how tricky it can be to make it into an icon, but it's another idea worth exploring. I think simplicity of the graphic/chair can relate to the simplicity of the assembling process. "Assembles by itself".

Comment: The idea might simply be to indicate that it is _not_ in a flat Ikea-like package. That it is 3D.

Comment: hmmmm this certainly does seem like 'a' possible solution. I currently have a set of very flat icons, I'll give this a try and see how it fits in.

Comment: Beat me to it.  This is exactly what I was thinking of when I asked what type of product it was.  The above mash-up is a little busy, but if @Jonny-C has some good "chair" icons to start with, making it look like it is coming fully-formed out of the box should be clear, especially with accompanying text.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Definitely! Mine is just an idea, by no means a good example of icon design ;)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ideal, but maybe a truck with chair on it.

Comment: When I first read this I imagined a lorry with a chair balanced on the roof, which seemed a bit abstract... Then I realised maybe you mean like a flat-bed truck with the chair on the back like it was being delivered? That makes a lot more sense!